# sistema de login utilizando o php e o mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Fiz alterações no programa mas continua a dar me erro...diz o seguinte:

> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given.

```
<?php
$username="username";
$pwd="pwd";
include ("database.php");
session_start();
    /*nesta linha----->*/ $res= mysqli_query("select username, pwd from user where username='$username' and pwd='$pwd'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($res)==0)
    {
        $res['username'] = $username;
        $res['pwd'] = $pwd;
        header('PaginaIniciaDoutora1.php');

    }
else{
    unset ($_SESSION['username']);
    unset ($_SESSION['pwd']);
    header('Pagina.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: `dar erro` É muito genérico, detalhe melhor seu problema. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Além de detalhar melhor, mostre o `database.php`. Se algo estiver errado nele vai influenciar o seu código tb.

Comment: Você deve utilizar `mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ...")`. O `mysqli_query` exige que o primeiro  parâmetro seja a conexão e o segundo seja a `query`.

Comment: peço desculpa a confusao mas ainda nao sei trabalhar bem com este site

Comment: @Inkeliz lol não tinha visto seu comentário...

Answer (score 3):

Tá errado isso

```
$username = $_POST;
$pwd = $_POST
```

Correto é assim

```
$username = $_POST[user];
$pwd = $_POST[pwd];
```

Esse usar e `pwd` vem do formulário `html` no `input name='user'` e `input name='pwd'`.

Comment: Provavelmente é este o problema, mas não dá para saber se é essa a solução. A última frase é a mais importante, o índice usado no `$_POST` deve ser o mesmo nome utilizado no `name` do respectivo `input`.

Answer (score 1):

> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given.

Espera 2 parâmetros, ou seja, o link e a query.

Então `mysqli_query($con, $query)`...

Onde `$con` é a variável de conexão e `$query`, sua consulta...